# FreeBSD pkg query by automatic flag?

Tags: freebsd

You can do a `pkg set -A ...` to set the automatic flag, but how do you do a `pkg query` for all packages with that automatic flag set?  I see you can do `pkg query -e '%#r != 0'`, but that's surely not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&format=html), try:

```
pkg query -e '%a =  1' %o
```